# Initialize 100 class data members to zero

Tags: c++

Is there a way to initialize all the data members of a class that has a user defined constructor?

```
class CTest
{
private: 
    int a = 0;
    BYTE b; CHAR* c; int d; int e; int f; int g;
public:
    CTest() b:(0)
    {
        c = 0;
    }
};
```

Imagine my class has 100 data members, and I want to initialize them all to zero.

Doing it 1 by 1 is not optimal. The workaround I'm using right now is: I put all those 100 data members in a structure which is the base for my class

like

```
class : public base_with_all_members
```

and when I want to reset  all the members I just do the following in the constructor or in a `initialize()` function for example.

```
*dynamic_cast<base_with_all_members*>(this) = {};
```

Which does properly clears all members.

Comment: I meant: *dynamic_cast<base_with_all_members*>(this) = {};

Comment: Why does your class have that many members in the first place? Sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: I second @BaummitAugen 's comment. A class with that many members is an unmaintainable design. You've just run into the first aspect of that. Instead of finding a technical solution, consider an alternative design.

Comment: Will in-class brace-or-equal initializer meet your need? If you just want to initializer all members to zero, you may consider making an aggregate and performing zero initialization with `{}`.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6891731/5756174).

Comment: Okay, maybe I made a mistake by over exaggerating. It does not have 230 data members, it has probably  around 100. And the reason why it has that many is because it's a huge project, and it's the main class in the project, so every other class relies on it. The design could have been better, but it's not because I started it when I was new at C++.

Comment: @Lingxi I think you have not fully read my question since that's what I'm currently doing. I was wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: @jblixr I have unique_ptr and a mutex in my class, and they cannot be copied so your solution doesn't work...

Comment: @Jose If so then you should have mentioned all these requirements in your question.

Comment: I second what the people before me said. The fact that you didn't know C++ very well *back then* is no reason not to refactor *now*.

Comment: Instead of 100 named members use an **array**. E.g. `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: Also covered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975262/constructor-to-specify-zero-initialization-of-all-builtin-members)  (probably a duplicate actually)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest will probably be to use the newer syntax for default value initialisation in this case. Sure it may be "not-optimal" in terms of typing time, but the generated code should be comparable.

```
class CTest
{
private: 
    int a = 0;
    BYTE b = 0;
    CHAR* c = nullptr;
    int d = 0;
    int e = 0;
    int f = 0;
    int g = 0;
public:
    CTest(): d(42)
    // initialiser list only needed is this particular
    // constructor doesn't initialise the value to 0
    {
    }
};
```

Another alternative is to farm off the data members to a POD style "data structure" and then initialise that in the class's constructor;

```
struct POD {
  int a;
  int b;
  std::unique_ptr<int> c;
  // etc.
};

class CTest {
  POD data_ = { };
};
```

Further alternatives could include using a [`static` of the above POD data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6891731/3747990) structure to initialise the member POD.

---

You have mentioned in the comments that you have **some data members that cannot be copied (but presumably can be moved)**, and that you are looking for some form of a "reset" function as well. The POD sample can be modified to;

```
class CTest {
  POD data_ = { };
public:
  void reset()
  {
    data_ = POD{}; // caters for moveable and copiable types
  }
};
```

[Sample here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6adf5a9c61a7aff9).

---

On a side note; this is a large number of data members. Maybe some further data division would be a good idea as well. Sure, I accept that this may be a really peculiar situation, but it may be worthwhile to consider some re-factoring anyway.

Comment: Hope the edit is OK, if not you may rollback.

Comment: I'm already using the second approach "farm off" the data members from a POD data structure, and the reason is because I can reset it anytime I want. I also mentioned your first approach on my question (u can see i did set a, b, c in different ways). The problem is that with such approach, I can't reset the class, I'd have to delete it and create a new one (because it has mutex, and uniqueptrs which cannot be copied) therefore I can't just do *myclassptr = {} .

Comment: @Jose, could you make use of `std::move`? You could then "move" and "empty or reset" object into the data member.

Answer (score 3):

Why not this? Then it would be in just one location for all of your constructors.

```
class Foo {
    public:
        Foo(): b(3) {}

    private:
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int d = 0;
        int e = 0;
};
```